# Not listed in the "marked as duplicate by" list

Tags: support, duplicate-answers

Yesterday I make this question: [test if file(s) from a given pattern exists in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907914/test-if-files-from-a-given-pattern-exists-in-bash)

I obviously did some homework before asking, but I couldn't find anything similar. Not much a surprise, Danny already had made a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363441/check-if-a-file-exists-with-wildcard-in-shell-script) and the answers was just a match to my question, Rawrgulmuffins find the question and post in a comment.

Since I knew my question was a duplicate, I flagged right right away, but my name is not listed in the `marked as duplicate by` list. Why?

Comment: Flagging is not the same as voting for close.

Comment: See your "helpful flags" link (number is clickable) in your profile page, you should see your flag there marked as "helpful".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you flag to close, you send a bat-signal to the moderators, who can then come by to vote to close (where one moderator vote is enough). The flag itself does not count as a vote though.

Regular users with enough reputation can *directly* vote to close instead. 5 regular users voted to close your question as a duplicate, and no moderator intervention was necessary.

You don't need to feel bad about not having found the duplicate question; your question adds more search keywords by which one now can find the original question for others that have the same question in the future.